# User Input - C (Not allowing certain characters)

Tags: c, user-input

I have a C program where the user will be entering integers or doubles into the command line as input. Negative numbers are allowed, but I have the issue of when a user enters some thing like this:

```
1-1
```

It just gets parsed as being a one. I created a function to test whether or not the user input is a valid number, but I'm not sure how to catch instances like that, or the same goes for input like 1+1, 1)2, so on.

Here is the function I created:

```
int check_number(char *userInput) {
int i;
//check each character
for (i = 0; userInput[i] != '\0'; i++){
    if (isalpha(userInput[i])){
        printf("Invalid input.\n");
        return -1;
    }
}       
return 0;
}
```

What should I do to not allow any other random characters (besides letters, since those are already getting tested with isalpha) in the middle of user input?

Comment: Try using `isdigit` for numbers if you're going to take that approach.

Comment: Only allow a `-` if it' the FIRST character  enetered. after that, only digits. Then keep an eye open for `.` and only allow one as well.

Comment: Well, it could be a floating point value, maybe even in exponential notation ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you want the first character to be either a minus or a digit (and maybe a period) all subsequent characters should be digits or a period. But you will probably also want to count the periods to make sure there is only one. If you want to accept scientific notation as well you will need to deal with that as well.

Checking for not isalpha is the wrong way around, you should check for the characters that are allowed.

Basically something like:

```
if (*userInput != '-' && !isdigit(*userInput))
  return -1;
int periods = 0;
while (*++userInput != 0) {
  if (*userInput == '.') {
    if (periods >= 1)
      return -1;
    ++periods;
    continue;
  }
  if (!isdigit(*userInput))
    return -1;
}
return 0;
```

Comment: I am trying to implement something similar, but now when I get to the final if statement, it fails even just with the number "1". Why would this be happening? I'm printing out the character to see what it is, and it says 1. But then why is it thinking it is not a digit?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured out because it was still parsing the newline character. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isdigit(userInput[i]) || userInput[i]=='.') {
  printf("Valid input.\n");
}
else return -1;
```

Comment: @iccthedral you are correct. I meant to demonstrate condition. fixed it now.